# How to add 'View in browser' link to the emails in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

How can i add 'view in browser' link to all the emails above the logo in magneto 2 to show the better email content to the user.

How we can achieve this. Any help can be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `<a href="">View in browser</a>` with empty href